# Solidity swap and add liquidity in contract

Tags: ethereum, smart-contract, solidity

Не понимаю в чем ошибка, при выполнении функции ZapInToken с парой токенов Cake/WBNB или Cake/USDT все завершается успешно. Если взять пару с комиссией 5% (pancakeswap), то выдает ошибку: "Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending? Returned error: {"jsonrpc":"2.0","error":"execution reverted","id":2392006384191628}"
Несмотря на то, что в контракте есть функция SetFee, и я установил там необходимую комиссию.

[ZapV2.sol](https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1stHPDy0_2lrEFccqfYnvkuvTq0yaDnpa?usp=sharing)

Пробовал изменить размер комиссии с помощью функции SetFee, необходимые approve были сделаны, токенов тоже хватало.